# Blackberry: Web Filtering

Tags: blackberry

I want to block the particular website from access to user. Is there is any API to block the website on blackberry.

Or is there is any way by which i can get the notification that which website is opened.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if you are device is using BES. I'm sure that it would have to be controlled by an IT Policy in the BES. A single, standalone application should not be able to simply take control such access controls.

I don't know much about how BES works, but my understanding is that if you have administrative access to the BES infrastructure, you can institute "IT Policies" that can control pretty much everything about the devices that operate with your infrastructure.

Comment: My doesn't have BES admin. I want some API's by which i can able to block the website.

Comment: A single, standalone application should not be able to simply take control such access controls.

Comment: If it is not possible then why the browser filter permission is given. The pernissions are only available when there is way to do that thing.